# DevExtreme DataGrid react component, problem with master/detail

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, master-detail, devextreme

I neeed some help to use Master/Detail pattern in DataGrid component of DevExtreme package for react.
I've got these errors:

#The above error occurred in the  component:
    in DataGrid (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App#

#TypeError: contentProvider is not a function#

It seems DataGrid does not want to work with Template as error occured only when template is present in code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DataGrid, {Column,FilterRow,Pager,Paging,Editing,ColumnLookup} from "devextreme-react/ui/data-grid";
import * as AspNetData from "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery";
import { Template } from 'devextreme-react/core/template';

export default class App extends React.Component<any, IProp> {
        ....

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <DataGrid
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                remoteOperations={true}
                masterDetail={{enabled: true, template: "details"}}>

                <Template name="details">
                    <div>Hello</div>
                </Template>


                <Column dataField="name" caption="Наименование ДУ"/>
                <Column dataField="mnemoCode" caption="Мнемокод" dataType="string" />

                <Pager
                    allowedPageSizes={[5, 10, 15, 20]}
                    showPageSizeSelector={true}
                    showInfo={true}
                />
                <Paging
                    defaultPageIndex={0}
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                />
                </DataGrid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Template component requires render or component props (transcluded content is not supported).

I would recommend using the MasterDetail config-component rather than the Template:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DataGrid, {Column,FilterRow,Pager,Paging,Editing,ColumnLookup, MasterDetail} from "devextreme-react/ui/data-grid";
import * as AspNetData from "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery";

const DetailComponent = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <p>Row data:
            <br/>
            {JSON.stringify(props.data)}
        </p>
    );
};

export default class App extends React.Component<any, IProp> {
        ....

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <DataGrid
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                remoteOperations={true}>

                <Template name="details">
                    <div>Hello</div>
                </Template>


                <Column dataField="name" caption="Наименование ДУ"/>
                <Column dataField="mnemoCode" caption="Мнемокод" dataType="string" />

                <Pager
                    allowedPageSizes={[5, 10, 15, 20]}
                    showPageSizeSelector={true}
                    showInfo={true}
                />
                <Paging
                    defaultPageIndex={0}
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                />
                <MasterDetail enabled={true} component={DetailComponent} />
                </DataGrid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But How do you set DetailComponent properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
         const masterDetailReturn = (props) => {
            return (
                <Template name="details"{...props}>
                   <div>Hello</div>
                 </Template>
             )};
-----------------------------------------------------------
             <MasterDetail
              enabled={true}
              component={masterDetailReturn}
            ></MasterDetail>
```